# django - session lifetime variable

Tags: django

For example, after a user login, I need to create a socket object that connect to a server and this socket object will be used in following operations of this user(I don't want to make a new connection in each user operation). But django's handler are all function so I have nowhere to put this socket object except use global dict.

I also try request.session['sock'] = socket_obj, but it report error: "expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found".

What is the typical way to do this in django?

Comment: if you want to store an object in the session, you will have to serialize/pickle it and for better handling base64encode it. But I am not sure whether you can do that to socket objects. Not sure what happens when you deserialize them.

Comment: I don't need save it to db and socket object can not be serialized. Generally, other network library or framework let user define their own session class: MySession, so object can be its data member. But django has no such thing, every request handler is function. Then it is hard to do this job.

Comment: @jean Hi, did you solve this problem?

Comment: No, I have not found things in django can support this. I have to manage all socket objects by myself

Comment: Too bad it does not work :(. I will try with ZODB or Redis, if it will be working I will post my results.